# unable do download file from ie11

Tags: download, internet-explorer-11

unable do download file from ie11, when click on download button post request send to the server. I checked in network section the response will come with content of file but in internet explorer 11   download prompt will not appear instead of that if display error page can not display and url will not correct . This program working fine with Mozilla Firefox.

I created a demo program which runs on my local host with same configuration ie11 works fine. but same program I tried to run on my production server tomcat getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem,but incase of PDF's my pdf file was not downloading from IE, in my case also the file was getting downloaded from the Firefox, I just checked the url, there is no such limit to the length of the url but in this I just reduced the length of the url and it worked, but I didn't get what IE does different in this maybe its the server which is handling the request from IE differently or while sending IE is doing something different, just check if this works, reduce the length of the url and try again.